# How can I connect to a USB serial device?

Tags: debian, usb, python, serial

I have a device with a USB serial port cable that I'd like to connect to my Raspberry Pi. The chipset for this USB to serial cable it the PL-2303 from Prolific Technology, Inc.

How can I read data from the serial connection of this device using Python?

Comment: Interesting question. This might help with the USB part: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/258/how-to-program-a-usb-device-with-debian-python

Comment: Is this two questions?  Specifically, 'how can I install the drivers for the serial devices?' and 'how can I connect to a serial device within Python?'.  The question regarding drivers would be long on this site.  However, the Python question might be more specific to a site like StackOverflow.  I would assume communicating with a serial device on Python is the same, regardless of the linux-based architecture or the install mechanism.

Comment: There should be no difference between communicating with the on board serial port (UART pins) and a USB serial port.

Comment: This questions reads: how do I get started with [Configuration \ Litmus test for PL2303 TTL to Serial] (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41553/usb-serial-port-configuration)?  Once the hardware is confirmed, then one can entertain running pyserial to pull data from the serial port

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To talk to a serial device using Python, use the pyserial module. If it is not available in your distribution, it can be installed by getting a copy of the source from [the pyserial project page](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) and running "python setup.py install"

Simple examples of using pyserial are available at [the short introduction](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports).

The module for the PL-2303 is available by default - see the [firmware GitHub repository](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/modules/3.1.9+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial) - when you plug the device in, you should see it fire up in `/var/log/messages`. I have connected up to an Arduino, and that "just worked" on communications port `/dev/ttyUSB0` (different device, driver, chipset, etc., so [your mileage may vary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)).

Comment: Connected the device and I now see /dev/ttyUSB0 so looks like there is a good chance it will "just work".

Comment: With pyserial installed and using the example miniterm I can see the data from the device :)

Answer (score 4):

The PL-2303 is well supported, and it will appear as `/dev/ttyUSBx`. No drivers are needed. Read it as you would any normal serial port. I haven't used Python, but in C++, I open() it in non-blocking mode, select() to see if there is data to be read, and then do a read().

Answer (score 4):

Download pySerial (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial)

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyserial/pyserial-2.7.tar.gz?raw=true -O pyserial-2.7.tar.gz
tar -xzf pyserial-2.7.tar.gz
cd pyserial-2.7
sudo python setup.py install
```

You can check ttyUSB availability with the line

```
ls -ltr /dev|grep -i ttyUSB
```

To view the serial output use

```
tail -f /dev/ttyUSB<NUMBER FROM ABOVE>
```

To break out crtl+c

Create a testserial.py file paste this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep
import serial

# Establish the connection on a specific port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600) 

x = 1 while True:
       print ser.readline() # Read the newest output 
       x += 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Great tutorial for that :

http://www.digitalmihailo.com/post/usb-programming-with-python-on-linux

A valuable source of information is http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm Complete

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also your second link is broken.