# USB Serial Port Configuration

Tags: usb, serial

Goal: configure serial to USB cable for 9600 8-N-1

Cable is plugged-in and observed:

```
root@OpenHAB:~# uname -a
Linux OpenHAB 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@OpenHAB:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
root@OpenHAB:~# ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

Is there a good reference for configuring a [Manhattan Serial to USB cable](http://www.manhattan-products.com/usb-to-serial-converter)

Is there a litmus test that can be performed from the command line to confirm that the serial port is online and at the ready?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! related (if not dupe): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7730/how-to-configure-serial-port-settings-of-dev-ttyama0/7733#7733

Comment: @Ghanima: thank you for the good link.  The goal is similar, however, the context is a little different (which may or may not make a difference).  The serial communication is to be performed through a USB adapter and not a pin on the rPi.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean configure the Linux end which is using /dev/ttyUSB0

`stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -cstopb cs8 -parenb 9600`

where

```
-cstopb is 1 stop bit
cs8 is 8 bits
-parenb is no parity
9600 is the baud rate
```

For full details `man stty`

Actually 9600-8-N-1 is the default.

The presence of /dev/ttyUSB0 implies the device is ready.  Unless the device supports handshake signals that's the best you can do without actually trying to read/write to the device.

Comment: Thank you for the actionable response.  Exactly what was called for.    Is there a way to prove that  Bus 001 Device 006: is represented by /dev/ttyUSB0?

Comment: @gatorback Not my area of knowledge.  Try the lsusb command.

Comment: root@OpenHAB:~# dmesg | grep pl2303
[ 1641.828007] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[ 1641.828171] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[ 1641.828287] pl2303 1-1.4:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 1641.832474] usb 1-1.4: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1871.361673] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1871.361757] pl2303 1-1.4:1.0: device disconnected
[ 1922.390068] pl2303 1-1.4:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 1922.394341] usb 1-1.4: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0