# Wiring-up and testing a sensor via Serial-to-USB

Tags: serial

My sensor (photodetector + LED)
 communicates (send-only: does not receive) via RS-232 at 9600 8-N-1.  It has  4 lines for

- power
- ground
- RS-232
- TTL Serial

The sensor's ground and RS-232 are connected to a [Manhattan Serial to USB cable.](http://www.manhattan-products.com/usb-to-serial-converter): Is there any reason why this would not work? or is there anything else to be done / considered?

Battery power has been applied and seems to power the sensor's LED (LED is bright).  Raspberry pi has been configured per

[The rPi serial-to-usb adapter has been tested as described (click) here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41553/usb-serial-port-configuration)  The sensor was plugged in: is it reasonable (or have I missed a step?) to expect that:

cat /dev/ttyUSB0

will display the raw data sent by the sensor?  Is there a better (surefire+easy) to confirm that serial data is streaming from the sensor? Thank you for actionable suggestions (executable commands).

Comment: You say it has been tested. Did it work? What is the output? `cat` is a poor choice - it depends what the sensor outputs. I would use a terminal program e.g. `minicom`. Incidentally if you have a ttl output why not connect to the Pi RxD (via a divider to ensure voltage does not exceed 3.3V).

Comment: What sensor? Are you sure it uses RS232 (+/- 12V) rather than serial TTL (0-5V)?.

Comment: @Milliways:  No, in the sense that I do not see inbound data from the sensor.  I need to perform a loopback tests starting from the Manhattan device to verify that it is not the problem (isolate the problem[s]).  Sensor outputs both 5V TTL and RS-232:  RS232 was selected for ease of physical connectivity, however, bridging 5V-TTL with a voltage divider is looking more and more attractive.

Comment: @joan:  good questions :)   A sophisticated Photo diode cricuit outputs both 5V TTL and RS-232.  The data sheet does not provide RS-232 voltage levels.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600` to ensure I get exactly what I expect at the correct speed.  You may have to `apt-get install screen` to make that work.

I don't see any issue with what you are doing assuming you got the TX/RX parts right and didn't accidentally cross the RS-232 signal levels onto something TTL level.  Note also your TTL serial could be 5 V, which could hurt things if connected directly to 3v3 logic.